# Where can a Victorian-level civilization find significant amounts of helium?

Tags: natural-resources

According to google

> Although helium is the second most abundant element in the universe,
>   most of it in the Earth's atmosphere bleeds off into space. Helium
>   used for industrial purposes is a byproduct of natural gas production

and

> Helium is cryogenically distilled out of natural gas

I want my world (or at least some areas of it) to have good access to helium. My world has a level of technology roughly on a par with the Victorians, how could they acquire this helium? Can it be mined along with methane?

The gas does not need to be pure, any concentration which will give a good level of lift is acceptable.

Comment: How pure do you need your helium to be?  95% pure helium as a lifting gas is much easier to obtain than 99.995% pure helium for scientific work.

Comment: Any amount which can give a good level of lift is good, it doesn't need to be pure as long as it floats.

Comment: ETA means estimated time of arrival. Did you mean Edit or NB?

Comment: hydrogen is much easier to obtain with some acid and metal

Comment: @Rowanas Edited To Add

Comment: @ratchetfreak true, but I'd rather helium as it's less prone to fireworks!

Comment: @Liath No real need to state "edited to add" or anything like that (and the abbreviation ETA is commonly read as Estimated Time of Arrival as Rowanas pointed out); just work it into the question. If someone is interested in how the post evolved, there is always the revision history.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling fair enough - I anticipated a few more questions (hence the first bullet point), I find it annoying when I answer something then the question evolves

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium#Natural_abundance) suggests that natural gas is the only source that is potentially viable - it can contain up to 7% helium, along with methane and other gases. (The upper atmosphere has parts which are largely helium, but I doubt those are recoverable with Victorian tech...)

Extracting it will require fractional distillation to separate it from the other gases, which means cryogenics of some sort. The boiling point of methane at sea level is 111K/−161°C, which we can use as a rough target.

The Victorians did have access to early refrigeration systems - [the first vapor-compression refrigerator was built in 1834](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refrigeration#Refrigeration_research), and commercial versions started to show up a couple of decades later. Most of the early gas-liquefaction experiments use high pressures as well as low temperatures, which confuses things a little, but several gases with boiling points at roughly the right temperature had been successfully liquified by the turn of the century.

Assuming access to natural gas wells, then, we can conclude that Victorian tech would certainly have been able to produce helium on a laboratory scale, and it sounds like late-Victorian techniques would probably have been good enough to do so on a commercially-viable scale.

Comment: Thanks - do you know roughly what percentage of methane/helium mining would yield?

Comment: Wikipedia says "up to 7% helium", so I'd guess somewhere in the low-to-mid single digits is normal.I couldn't find any detailed breakdowns of what raw gas is made of, unfortunately, but I expect methane makes up most of it. There will be other gases as well, but most of them will condense out at (very roughly) similar temperatures to the methane anyway.

Comment: I imagine it depends on the particular deposits... best burn off the methane though or that town's gonna really smell!

Comment: @TobyYuretich, please **[edit]** your answer to incorporate new information requested in comments rather than responding with comments. Comments are second-class citizens on Stack Exchange and may be deleted for virtually any reason.

Comment: @Liath, methane is odorless.  You'll want to burn it off, yes, but to prevent undetectable explosion hazards rather than because of smell.